# When using the 'rinruby' gem on rails, I'm so far unable to use png("path/to/file.png") & dev.off() to dump heatmaps etc to a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, r, export

Though my original script was far more sophisticated than this, I'm not even able to get this script working through `rails c`

Here's what I tried, but in all fairness, it doesn't matter what the example is. Functionality appears to breakdown when the graphic-generation process starts.

**from `rails c`**

```
R.eval("numbers <- c(12,34,56,20,44,65)")
R.eval("png('sample.png')")
R.eval("plot(numbers)")
R.eval("dev.off()")
#nothing happens
```

**from `irb`**

```
R.eval("numbers <- c(12,34,56,20,44,65)")
R.eval("png('sample.png')")
R.eval("plot(numbers)")
R.eval("dev.off()")
#action!
```

**so outside of rails, as in the ruby irb for example, all is working well. This is an issue exclusive to the rails environment**

Answer (score 5):

Specify the app/assets path to store the file:

```
require 'rinruby'

R.image_path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "sample.png").to_s
R.eval("numbers <- c(12,34,56,20,44,65)")
R.eval("png(filename=image_path)")
R.eval("plot(numbers)")
R.eval("dev.off()")
```

The png should show up in the app/assets directory and you can use it in a Rails view like any other image.

```
<%= image_tag 'sample.png' %>
```

Comment: Nice example there is so little documentation out there. Simple and immensely helpful